# Mockito's @After and verifyNoMoreInteractions

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I want to make sure every test verifies all the interactions with its mocks, so I just added a method annotated with @After with a verifyNoMoreInteractions with all the mocks as arguments.

```
@After
public void after(){
  verifyNoMoreInteractions(mock1,mock2,mock3,...)
}
```

It works, but if an interaction occurs where none was expected, how can you know which test is the problematic one?

Comment: Check my updated answer. Looks like it's what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misusing method `verifyNoMoreInteractions()`. It should be called inside each test you want to verify.

From the other hand `@After` is supposed to be used for cleaning/closing the resourses used by your test methods.

What you need is a custom `TestWatcher` rule. See below an example of such rule:

```
public class VerifyNoMoreInteractionsRule extends TestWatcher {

    private final List<Object> mocks = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Object mock){
        mocks.add(mock);
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded(Description description) {
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(mocks.toArray());
    }

}
```

Then you can use it in your unit tests:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class VerifyTest {

    @Rule
    public VerifyNoMoreInteractionsRule noMoreInteractionsRule = new VerifyNoMoreInteractionsRule();

    @Mock
    private YourMock yourMock;

    @Mock
    private AnotherMock anotherMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        // Register the mocks you want to verify after each test
        noMoreInteractionsRule.add(yourMock);
        noMoreInteractionsRule.add(anotherMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        // Put your ordinary test code here
    }

}
```

The rule will be applied to each test.

Comment: love it, but how do you know which test is the one that's failing?

Comment: The rule will make it fail. So it'll look as it failed itself. The same effect as putting verifier inside each of your tests.

Comment: is there a way to know which test is the one that's missing the verifications?

Comment: If you declare the `@Rule` in your test class then in will be applied to all methods annotated with `@Test`.

Comment: I actually meant showing the failing test as part of the error message: @Override
        protected void succeeded(Description description) {
            mocks.stream().forEach((mock)-> {
                try {
                    verifyNoMoreInteractions(mock);
                } catch (NoInteractionsWanted e) {
                    System.err.println("failed test " + description.getDisplayName());
                    throw e;
                }
            });
        }

Answer (score 4):

`@After` is executed right after each test of this class finished execution. Regardless if the test failed or not. Then if errors happen in the `@After` method it could cover/hide the errors happened in the test method...

Note that `@AfterClass` Is executed after all tests of this class finished execution.

Generally speaking I found it is a good style to have a behavioural Test split in three parts- call it A/A/A or call it Given/When/Then

**Arrange / Given part:**
Setup up objects and behaviour

**Act or When:**
Execute implementation

**Assert or Then:**
Verify behaviour and results (Hint: this is where the `verifyNoMoreInteractions` goes)

Comment: I actually go with the Given/When/Then arrangement, and in the Then part I place the verify as usual, but since I wanted to make sure that every person that creates a test verifies all the interactions, I thought it could be a good idea to have the verifyNoMoreInteractions in the @After method

Comment: You can do it like that, why not. But I like to set up most resources within the test itself, so the After method won’t know the mocks I want to test.

Comment: Yeah that's the way I've always done it, but some tests are just way too large, so I thought about having the mocks as attributes of the class instead rather than declaring them in each test, then I thought about the verifyNoMoreInteractions in the @After method

Comment: If the test is too large I would check if the class/method is doing too much, keyword separation of concerns

Answer (score 2):

For JUnit5 it can be done using `AfterEachMethodAdapter` where you check whether the test has thrown an exception. If yes, no mocks are verified:

```
public class MockAwareTest {

    @RegisterExtension
    public MockVerifier mockVerifier = new MockVerifier();


    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mockVerifier.addMocks(...);
    }

}
```

And the `MockVerifier`:

```
public class MockVerifier implements AfterEachMethodAdapter {

    private final List<Object> mocks = new LinkedList<>();

    public void addMocks(final Object... mock) {
        mocks.addAll(asList(mock));
    }

    @Override
    public void invokeAfterEachMethod(
            final ExtensionContext context,
            final ExtensionRegistry registry) {
        // if the test didn't fail, check the mocks
        if (context.getExecutionException().isEmpty()) {
            verifyNoMoreInteractions(mocks.toArray());
        }
    }

}
```